# Asterisk + SIP 404 not found

Tags: sip, asterisk

I want to make a small Asterisk server in my house. I installed asterisk on my Ubuntu
and I use 2 computers, in order to connect to one another. when I connect I can see in Wireshark that registrar ok. here is the output of **sip show peers** command:

```
Name/username              Host                                    Dyn Forcerport ACL Port     Status     
uriel/uriel                192.168.1.101                            D   N      5060     Unmonitored 
vibrant/vibrant            192.168.1.100                            D   N      5060     Unmonitored 
2 sip peers [Monitored: 0 online, 0 offline Unmonitored: 2 online, 0 offline]
```

But the problem is when I call sip:vibrant@192.168.1.200 from uriel I get 404 not found.

And sorry for my English.

as user mealstrom asked:
sip.conf

```
[vibrant]
type=friend
username=vibrant
secret=
host=dynamic
context=tutorial
nat=yes
qualify=yes

[uriel]
type=friend
username=uriel
secret=
host=dynamic
context=tutorial
nat=yes
qualify=yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a dialplan. In your sip.config you set default context for each sip user. Then in extensions.conf you create this context and save the dialplan in it. You can see asterisk's examples - they are pretty good. Of course if you still have problems ask here :)